# Block all post requests except specified in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, post, python-requests

I am on looking for .htaccess code that block all post requests expect one form with action a query string ?pub=123 i hope you understand what i am saying thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, so only a general, vague answer is possible:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^pub=123$
RewriteRule ^/?path/to/action [F]
```

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: is this will  deny all other post requests?

Comment: It will return a http 403 (forbidden) for _all_ requests to `/path/to/action` that do _not_ have that sole http get parameter. If you want to further limit this to only http post requests (but _not_ block other request types), then you need to add another condition.

Comment: Actually my site is under attack by sending malware through Post requests.I deny all post requests iin .htaccess but the issue is there is quotation form which needs post request allowed in order to  work.So what u suggest

Comment: What do you mean by "what I suggest"? If you want to block and allow one exception then above should work.

Comment: can u plz explain this line plz.is this "path/to action is place holder"
RewriteRule ^/?path/to/action [F]

Comment: You need to specify a pattern to the rewrite rule that it gets applied to. The path of the request. So the absolute path your form sends its values to, besides that GET argument you mentioned. So actually the path you specify in your form's action attribute, but take care to use its absolute form.